# Cannot copy CSV to database table because access is denied

Tags: linux, postgresql, csv, permissions

I have a CSV file named `CropData.csv` that I want to copy into a postgreSQL table called `Crops` as follows:

```
\copy "Crops" FROM '/home/erooijak/zaaikalender/CropData.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

I also tried using COPY instead of \copy. Unfortunately, both attemps give the message:

> ERROR:  could not open file "/home/erooijak/zaaikalender/CropData.csv" for reading: Permission denied

I tried making the user `postgres` owner of the files and setting the permissions to read write and execute as follows:

```
su
chown postgres:postgres CropData.csv 
chmod 777 CropData.csv
```

This still gives the same error.

When I display the properties of a file using the explorer I see this:

[image: Visible that postgres is owner]

Can someone explain to me why I cannot copy the CSV into a table and how I would be able to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it was by copying the CSV via the GUI tool `pgadmin3` as follows:

[image: A visual solution]

Still not clear why I cannot get it to work in a command.